# What ciphers are used to encrypt sections of the ASP.NET Web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encryption

I'm looking at the MS documentation at these links:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas.aspx

The documentation states the following:

> Now that the identity of your ASP.NET application has read access to the RSA key container for the default RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider object, you will encrypt sections of the Web.config file for your ASP.NET application by using that key container.

This seems to imply that the protected sections in the Web.config file will be encrypted via RSA, and in the example XML code, I do see the following code

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
```

However, I also see the following code, which seems to suggest that TDES-CBC is used as a cipher:

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
```

What ciphers are being used to encrypt what data?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ might yield more detailed information for you.

Comment: I was just looking more closely at my own config and noticed what you have in your question. I see what you're saying better now, even after answering below. It's almost as if the 'section' is using tripledes and the keys/values are using rsa.

Comment: @wazz by section you mean the <connectionStrings> section? So everything that is encapsulated by <connectionStrings> is encrypted by TDES? What keys/values are encrypted using RSA? And is there any document that can confirm this?

Comment: I can't confirm it with docs, it's just what the result looks like, whether it's conn strings section, app settings section, smtp section, etc.. Probably have to dig into provider classes to see if two ciphers are really being used.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from various docs:

You can specify your own protected configuration provider or you can use one of the providers built into ASP.NET.

By default, the **Machine.config** file specifies the following protected configuration providers [included in the .NET Framework]:

DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider. Uses the Windows Data Protection
   API (DPAPI) to encrypt and decrypt data.

RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider. **Uses the RSA encryption algorithm** to encrypt and decrypt data. [default.]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2(v=vs.100).aspx

```
// Encrypt the <connectionStrings> section.
connectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
```

"In some cases, you might need to encrypt information using an algorithm other than those available with the RSA or DPAPI providers." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfc2t3az(v=vs.100).aspx

TripleDES provider sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.100).aspx